Не воспроизводится звук в фоновом режиме в Safari с сайта
Всем привет!
Пишу веб-приложение и столкнулся с проблемой, ко мне приходят данные через AJAX, и в зависимости от этих данных либо ничего не происходит,либо должен проиграться звуковой сигнал, если документ скрыт(document.hidden), но к сожалению на айфонах Safari звука нет(
Файл со звуком в формате mp3 в теге . На сайте активность происходит, то есть перед тем как звук запустить, клик по экрану делаю, знаю, что без этого звук вообще не проиграется, но все делаю. Может кто-то сталкивался с похожей проблемой, подскажите?
